# Reverse countdown using JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, countdown

I'm trying to develop a small auction plugin, which works in reverse. There's a starting price which decreasing in every minute. So let's say:

> Starting price: 300 $ 
> Actual price: 150 $ 
>  Decrease: 50 $ in 
>   every minute

When you click on the bid button, you win the auction, and can buy the product on the actual price.

I have a working html file controlled by JavaScript, but I need everyone to see the same actual price. How should I do that? I'm trying to execute the JavaScriptin a chat plugin called jappix, but I have absolutely no idea how to do that, and I don't think that it would be fast enough to make it in PHP.

Comment: You can use Ajax long polling for this.
Refer: http://www.abrandao.com/2013/05/11/php-http-long-poll-server-push/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to technically solve the problem:

**1)** [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

[How to implement Comet with PHP](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

**2)** [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)
Here is a [Simple Chat Server Example](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket) and a Framework [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/), which should help you getting grips on websockets.